# Using System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy with Unity causes issues when trying to get value of a public property

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a RealProxy with Unity3D and I'm getting this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
(wrapper ldfld) System.Object.__ldfld_wrapper_000001804BA82020_System.Single(object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
Player.PlayerController.Setup (UMVC.Core.MVC.Interfaces.IBaseView`1[TModel] view) (at Assets/Player/PlayerController.cs:27)
UMVC.Core.MVC.BaseView`2[TModel,TController].Awake () (at <51bf8ffda04c457aa9f14160e1112cbf>:0)
```

This error is thrown when I try to get a public member of my `PlayerModel` like `playerModelInstance.jumpPower`.

**The code behind `PlayerController.cs`:**

```cs
namespace Player
{
    
    public class PlayerController : BaseController<PlayerModel>
    {
        public override void Setup(IBaseView<PlayerModel> view)
        {
            base.Setup(view) // you can see the implementation below
            // in theory the `Model` is fully initialized after base.Setup(view)

            Debug.Log(Model.jumpPower); // THE CODE IS CRASHING HERE
        }
        
    } //end PlayerController
}
```

**The `PlayerModel`**:

```
using System;
using UMVC.Core.MVC;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Player
{
    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerModel : BaseModel
    {
        public float jumpPower = 12f;
        

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            isOnFieldDidUpdateEnabled = false;
            isOnFieldWillUpdateEnabled = false;
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

**The `ModelProxy`: you can view the implementation here: [UMVC.Core/MVC/ModelProxy.cs](https://github.com/loic-lopez/UMVC/blob/master/UMVC.Core/MVC/ModelProxy.cs)**

**The `BaseModel`**:

which inherit from `MarshalByRefObject` **in order to make RealProxy working**.

**The BaseController**:

```cs
using UMVC.Core.MVC.Interfaces;

namespace UMVC.Core.MVC
{

    public abstract class BaseController<TModel> where TModel : BaseModel
    {
        protected TModel Model { get; set; }
        protected IBaseView<TModel> View;
        protected ModelProxy<TModel> ModelProxy;

        public virtual void Setup(IBaseView<TModel> view)
        {
            View = view;
            ModelProxy<TModel> modelProxy = ModelProxy<TModel>.Bind(View.GetModel());
            Model = modelProxy.GetTransparentProxy();
            Model.Initialize();
            ModelProxy = modelProxy;
            SubscribeEvents();
        }

        public virtual void LateSetup()
        {
        }

        protected virtual void SubscribeEvents()
        {
            ModelProxy.OnFieldWillUpdate += View.OnFieldWillUpdate;
            ModelProxy.OnFieldDidUpdate += View.OnFieldDidUpdate;
        }


    }
}
```

```cs
namespace UMVC.Core.MVC
{
    [Serializable]
    // MarshalByRefObject are necessary in order to RealProxy be able to work
    public abstract class BaseModel : MarshalByRefObject, IBaseModel
    {
        public bool isOnFieldWillUpdateEnabled = true;
        public bool isOnFieldDidUpdateEnabled = true;
        
        public virtual void Initialize()
        {
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Note:** The ModelProxy is working outside of a Unity Project because Unit Tests cover this code, visible from [UMVC.Core/Tests/MVCTests.cs](https://github.com/loic-lopez/UMVC/blob/master/UMVC.Core/Tests/MVCTests.cs).

**EDIT 1:**

Changing `Debug.Log(Model.jumpPower);` to `Debug.Log(Model);` outputs

```
Player.PlayerModel
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Player.PlayerController:Setup(IBaseView`1) (at Assets/Player/PlayerController.cs:27)
UMVC.Core.MVC.BaseView`2:Awake()
```

So it seems that `Model` is correctly instanciated but I can't access to my public members.

Comment: another thing not supported by Unity I guess https://twitter.com/petersonjm1/status/1082610640429162496

Comment: @Aybe Thanks for your comment but I'm not using IL2CPP in my project

Comment: I knew you'd reply that, take it as a general advice, when it doesn't work out of the box, then surely something's missing. Add to that the fact that Unity uses a custom version of Mono. See for an alternative

Comment: Thanks do you know something that act like `RealProxy `?

Comment: From [https://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) it seems that realproxy are integrated in Mono

Comment: Are you trying to marshal by ref across app domains? Separate processes?  It's much more common these days to use serializable types and always marshal types by value across boundaries.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft `UMVC.Core.MVC` is a library that contains base classes (like `RealProxy`) to extends in a Unity project and I import the DLLs in my Unity project (you can see it here: [UMVC/UMVC.Core/MVC](https://github.com/loic-lopez/UMVC/tree/master/UMVC.Core/MVC)), I don't use separate processes because the `public virtual void Setup(IBaseView<TModel> view)` is called by the `Awake` Unity event.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Does `IObservable<T>` can be an alternative to `RealProxy`?

Comment: No, that's unrelated.  But perhaps `ObservableCollection<T>` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft To make things easier to understand, `ModelProxy` is trying to call events before an after an affectation of a field like a « field watcher » (and it works outside of unity) without adding manually to each field, a call to an event as `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I will try later to dig into `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is the low-magic way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for reply @DavidBrowne-Microsoft but sometimes a `Model` can have a lot of public members, this is why I implemented `ModelProxy` in order to "magically" invoke the `before` and `after` update events. It can be tedious to write a setter and call by our-self a method that will call those events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a replacement of `RealProxy` I have used a pattern like the microsoft `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```cs
public interface INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   event Delegates.OnFieldWillUpdate OnFieldWillUpdate;
   event Delegates.OnFieldDidUpdate OnFieldDidUpdate;
}
```

Modified my `BaseModel` as follows:

```cs
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseModel: IBaseModel, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public bool isOnFieldWillUpdateEnabled = true;
    public bool isOnFieldDidUpdateEnabled = true;

    public virtual event Delegates.OnFieldWillUpdate OnFieldWillUpdate;
    public virtual event Delegates.OnFieldDidUpdate OnFieldDidUpdate;

    public virtual void Initialize() {}

    protected virtual void RaiseOnFieldWillUpdate<T>(T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        var eventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);

        object oldValue;

        var type = GetType();
        var field = type.GetField(eventArgs.PropertyName);

        if (field != null) {
            oldValue = field.GetValue(this);
        }
        else {
            oldValue = type.GetProperty(eventArgs.PropertyName) ? .GetValue(this);
        }

        OnFieldWillUpdate?.Invoke(this, newValue, oldValue, eventArgs);
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseOnFieldDidUpdate<T>(T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        OnFieldDidUpdate?.Invoke(this, newValue, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, Expression<Func<T>> property) {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;

        string propertyName = ((MemberExpression) property.Body).Member.Name;

        if (isOnFieldWillUpdateEnabled) RaiseOnFieldWillUpdate(value, propertyName);
        field = value;
        if (isOnFieldDidUpdateEnabled) RaiseOnFieldDidUpdate(field, propertyName);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Use it like that:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class MvcModel: BaseModel 
{

   [SerializeField] private int val;

    public int Value {
        get => val;
        set => Set(ref val, value, () => Value);
    }
}
```